# why my sql file is empty using cron job to take sql backup?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cpanel

im using cron job to take sql backup but every time cron job creating an empty backup file what's wrong in query `/usr/bin/mysqldump -u dbusername -p 'password' dbname > /home/dir/public_html/backup.sql`

[image]

Comment: Is the path correct? and does the cron user has the right permissions?

Comment: As an aside it probably isn't a good idea to put a dump of your database in your public HTML space since anyone would be able to get it there.

Comment: yes path is correct it is creating file backup.sql but empty im unaware of  how to add "cron user has the right permissions" and yes im aware any one can access to db but im still testing later i will change path

Comment: When you do the dump command, you are using a specific user, let's say mysql.  Is the cron setup with that user?  Or root?  Anyway, once you validate the user, then you have to know that cron does not setup your environment like when you login.  So you should load the environment (ex. `. ~mysql/.bashrc`).  There might be something in there mysql requires to perform the dump correctly.